# Output Static ID/Serial using Apple Wallet

Tags: ios, iphone, applepay

My iPhone 6s detects my security systems RFID readers and I can authenticate my credit card in my apple wallet to it. The access gets denied because the token that is presented from Apple wallet changes each time I present to the reader.

Is there a way to make a pass/card in my Apple wallet to present the same ID each time it’s presented?

Also, bonus question, are we any closer to actually getting an Apple product to open a door like in the September event video?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make a pass/card in my Apple wallet to present the
>   same ID each time it’s presented?

Yes, NFC readers that can read Apple Wallet passes can read encrypted static data from the pass. This is possible with Google Pay passes too. At [PassNinja](http://passninja.com), we are launching a product to help with reading and decrypting both Apple Wallet and Google Pay pass payloads.

> Also, bonus question, are we any closer to actually getting an Apple
>   product to open a door like in the September event video?

Yes to this also. See [this video](https://www.instagram.com/p/BldwjV4HAmu/?taken-by=passninja) for an example of a lock opened by an Apple Wallet pass.

Disclosure: I work for [Flomio](http://www.flomio.com), the company behind PassNinja.